# Navigation current maneuver not following current route [iOS SDK]

Tags: react-native, here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk

I am simulating turn-by-turn navigation for a truck route and sometimes the currentManeuver does not follow the path of the route. After passing the maneuver navigation will recalculate and will keep trying direct me somewhere that is not my route's destination. Here is a screenshot of the [image: current maneuver take an exit, instead of keeping straight on the highway]. TTS for maneuver [After one mile keep right and take the exit].

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about how to give a reproducible example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please specify which HERE SDK edition you are using, Premium or Navigate? Also, the code to handle the deviation from the route would be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the navigation map component was not unmounting after leaving the page, so multiple routes were active at the same time causing the constant rerouting and incorrect maneuvers.
After using useFocusEffect to mount/unmount the nav map, each time i navigate to the map only 1 route is added to the map object.